# How to open a text file and rename it with the text from the file?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to rename some text files with applescript using a string that is in the text of the file.  The files are old usenet messages that ended up with severely messed up names like REARIY-1.  I have figured out how to read the file and find the text string I want (it is proceeded by SUBJECT:)  I have also figured out how to rename a file if I have the user type in the text, but I have had trouble opening the file to read it and also getting the path to allow me to rename it.

The best I have done so far is the following (which required the user to be careful to select the same file twice):

```
set foo to choose file with multiple selections allowed

set fileAlias to foo as alias

set footext to read file ((choose file with prompt "phhhht") as string)

set targetText to "Subject:"
set extractedProperty to ""
set foundIt to "Target text not found."



set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
try
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {ASCII character 13}
set bar to text items of footext
repeat with thisItem in bar

    if thisItem contains targetText then
        set foundIt to thisItem
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
on error
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
end try

try
if thisItem contains "not found" then
    display dialog "text not found, filename not changed"
    tell me to quit
end if
end try

repeat with thisWord in words of foundIt
if contents of thisWord is not targetText then
    set extractedProperty to extractedProperty & thisWord & " "
end if
end repeat

set extractedProperty to characters 9 thru -2 of extractedProperty as text

display dialog extractedProperty -- for check only

tell application "Finder"
set name of fileAlias to (extractedProperty & ".txt")
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your third line from:

```
set foo to choose file with multiple selections allowed
set fileAlias to foo as alias
set footext to read file ((choose file with prompt "phhhht") as string)
```

to

```
set footext to read file (foo as string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
    set fileList to choose file with multiple selections allowed

set targetText to "Subject:"
set targetTextCount to count of characters in targetText
set extractedProperty to ""

repeat with thisItem in fileList
    set footext to paragraphs of (read file (thisItem as string))

    repeat with this_item in footext
        if this_item contains targetText then

            set extractedProperty to characters from ((offset of targetText in this_item) + targetTextCount) to -1 of this_item as string

            --log extractedProperty
            tell application "Finder"
                set name of (thisItem as alias) to (extractedProperty & ".txt")
            end tell
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
end repeat
```